# File integrity/changes audit with SMPP/SMTP alert and reporting feature - File watcher

Tags: file-management, email, monitoring, sms, sysadmin

Here's my use case.

1. As a Sysadmin, I would like to monitor on a Linux server any changes to a specific/predefined file or directory, so that I can answer via a report the following questions : who modified what and when ? What's a the diff of of the file before and after changes
2. As a Manager, I would like to recieve via an SMS (SMPP) or an email (SMTP) a summary report off daily changes that occured on a specific/predefined file/directory

Hence, the software would be able to watch specific/predefined files and send reports via sms or email of who modified, when and possibly what was modified on a Linux server

It sounds like a combination of AIDE and GIT but it's not in the context of developpement (build). We are more in the run (as in think ; build ; run) for this request

What software can I use to do that ?

Comment: If you want to delete your own post, just do it. But besides, it wasn't anything bad with the original one.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your own post. You can delete it if you like, but don't vandalise it. Once submitted you have agreed that it belongs to everyone under CC BY-SA 4.0 See [What is the license for the content I post?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry. It was not my intention. I just thought it was a bad question since It was not raising anyanswer nor views

Comment: @Alejandro Sorry. Please see my comment above for the reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netwrix Change Tracker, seems that fits most of the requirements here.

https://www.netwrix.com/security_configuration_management_software.html

https://www.newnettechnologies.com/group-notifications-with-change-tracker-gen7.html

= Support for Linux

== Supports Linux out of the box

= Who modified

== Direct quote from their product page

> "Determine exactly which systems were modified and when by reviewing a
> complete history of all changes."

= What

==See above

= When

== See above

= What's a the diff of of the file before and after changes

== Now this is tricky. I don't believe this is supported as this requires a constant diff when a file is changed.

= Notifications (email or SMS)

== Supports Emails at least, check second link above

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Both are very good. Especially Netwrix